# How do I pass username/password credentials from php client to self-hosted wcf service?

Tags: c#, php, wcf, wcf-authentication

I have a self-hosted wcf service that just adds 2 numbers and returns the value.  It works fine, but I am not sure how I can send the username and password through the php client, so it will validate against my CustomUserNamePasswordValidator.  Here is the implementation for the Add Method:

```
public class MathService : IMathService
{
    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    } 
}
```

Here is my current App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="WcfWithPhp.MathService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfWithPhp.IMathService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/MathService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am starting the service like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfWithPhp.MathService));
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Math Service Host");
    Console.WriteLine("Service Started!");

    foreach (Uri address in host.BaseAddresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + address);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the host...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
}
```

For the php client, I am doing:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

echo "WCF Test\r\n\r\n";

// Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8731/MathService?wsdl");

$obj->x = 2.5;
$obj->y = 3.5;

$retval = $client->Add($obj);

echo "2.5 + 3.5 = " . $retval->AddResult;

?>
```

The above works fine without authentication, but I want to be able to authenticate the username and password from the phpclient.  When they try to access my service, I want the username and password to validate through the overriden Validate method of the UserNamePasswordValidator, which is currently defined as:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        // check if the user is not test
        if (userName != "test" || password != "test")
            throw new FaultException("Username and Password Failed");
 }
```

I am just using test and test as an example for the username and password.  I know I have to set the modify the behavior configuration and do a binding configuration, so the service will use the CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, but since I don't know PHP, I am not sure how to send the credentials from php to the wcf service and once the credentials are sent, I don't know how to set it in the wcf service.  I am not creating a wcf service.  I thought I could do `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName` and `client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password`, but this is only if I am creating .NET client which I am not.

Another question I had was that if the client is a php client, am I restricted to only basicHttpBinding?

Also,  ideally what I would like to do is send a soap request from the php client to the wcf service, so if anyone can point me in the right direction for this, it would be great.

I just tried the following, but it didn't work (Add was called, but it wasn't authenticated)

```
$sh_param = array('userName' => 'test', 'passWord' => 'test2');

$headers = new SoapHeader('http://localhost:8731/MathService.svc','UserCredentials',   
$sh_param,false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
```

UPDATE:
My PHP Soap Client initialization is now:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8731/MathService?wsdl',
                         array('login' => "test2", 
                               'password' => "test",
                               'trace'=>1));
```

By doing the above, it added the following in the Request:

```
`Authorization: Basic dGVzdDI6dGVzdA==`
```

However, my wcf service which is hosted in a console app, is not picking up this authorization, I have a custom username validator which has a hard-coded value of test for the username and test for the password, but when I try "test2" for the login, it is still calling the method.  I am using TransportWithCredentialOnly and Message="UserName"

Comment: Please do not send your username and password in plain text.

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand, this is just for testing.  I just want it to be able to get the username and password first from php and set it in the wcf service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try SoapClient constructor overload:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('login'    => "some_name",
                                            'password' => "some_password"));
```

And here is the doc: http://www.php.net/manual/pl/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: ok, I tried this and it in the request, I see  Authorization: Basic dGVzdDI6dGVzde93==, but my WCF Service is not setting the credentials.

Comment: I changed the transport clientCredentialType to Basic and it worked.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.